# After install my app has no start button on some Android versions

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio-4.0

I have coded an app with Android Studio and Kotlin. Also I did build an Apk-file. After this I installed the Apk-file on Android 4.4 and all was fine. Then I tried to install it on Android 8.0 and on Android 9.0. Both installations gone through, but had a critical miss. After closing the installation I can find the app in the app list of Android. There I can uninstall and stop the app from running, but there is no start button. If I start the app direct after installation, when you get asked if you want to start the app, it runs perfect. I have no clue what the problems is. All installations were on real devices, no emulator. I give the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="android.example.schach">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/icon_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category 
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

What did I do to solve my problem? I did some Internet search, but had no success in finding a related problem.

In build.gradle(:app) I have:

```
compileSdkVersion 29
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 29
```

To clarify what i mean with start button: Go to manage your apps. Search the app name in the app list. Click on it and there you have some buttons for your app, like uninstall, stop it and run. In my case run is missing on Android 8 and 9, but on Android 4.4 it is available.

Comment: have you specified the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion for Android 9.0?

Comment: By "start button" do you mean the application icon?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, dont know if this really qualifies as an answer, but after trying again on Android 8 the installation was successfull (same Apk-file as before). As this installation was for the target device everything is fine :).